# WPF ListView Headers

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I was wondering, Most wpf list view the header/columns are movable. Is it possible so that we can make them non-draggable or movable at all?
does anyone know what this property is called by any chance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

MSDN is your friend ;)

- [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) on MSDN
- [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx) on MSDN
- [GridView.AllowsColumnReorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.allowscolumnreorder(v=VS.90).aspx) on MSDN

Specifically, the property you're looking for is the [GridView.AllowsColumnReorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.allowscolumnreorder(v=VS.90).aspx)

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">
    <!-- content -->
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: If MSDN is my friend, my wife should be jealous of stackoverflow.

Comment: can verify comment